# How to run integration test for a particular class in grails 3.0

Tags: grails-3.0

I am new to grails, and am trying to run  already existing integration tests for a particular class (using grails 3.0.11).(I don't want to run ALL the test classes, just a single one)

1. Is it possible to do that for integration tests or can only Unit tests be run in that way?
2. If yes, then can somebody suggest how it can be done?

The test class looks like this

```
@TestFor(ClassToBeTested)  
@Mock([])  
class ClassToBeTestedSpec extends Specification {  
...  
}
```

I have tried the following after looking through posts here,

```
$ grails test-app -integration ClassToBeTested
```

But I get below error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':integrationTest'.
> No tests found for given includes: [ClassToBeTested]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For a test class in a non-default package:

`grails test-app -integration *.ClassToBeTested`

Or with gradle:

`--tests *.ClassToBeTested`

Comment: thanks.. but its still not working. My test class is in a non-default package.

Comment: I get below exception when trying your suggestion  
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
  
* What went wrong:  
Execution failed for task ':integrationTest'.  
> No tests found for given includes: [*.ClassToBeTested]

Comment: Integration tests have to be in /src/integration-test/groovy/

Answer (score 2):

I had to add 'Tests' to the end of the argument to make this work with JUnit.  Perhaps Spock requires the text 'Spec' on the end too?

With JUnit, I needed to enter a pattern that matches the actual test class, including 'Tests':

```
--tests *ClassToBeTestedTests
```

I am guessing that using Spock, it might be something like (I don't have any Spock tests to verify this on):

```
--tests *.ClassToBeTestedSpec
```

Comment: Sorry if I misled you unintentionally. By ClassToBeTested I was just referring to the name of the class that was to be tested. It could be any class that you intend to test.

Comment: I meant, you might need to include the 'Spec' on the end.  I had to include the 'Tests' on the end of the argument for JUnit.

Answer (score 1):

In Grails 3, you can run a specific test like this:

```
grails test-app com.yourpackage.yourapp.SomeWhateverSpec
```

or use star if you don't want to write the package hierarchy:

```
grails test-app *.SomeWhateverSpec
```

Don't forget to add the **Spec** word at the end, otherwise it won't work.